# How to compare grouped data between two dates using the mongodb aggregate framework

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider a data set as follows

```
Sector Value Date
a      2     1/1/2015
b      5     1/1/2015
c      8     1/1/2015 
a      3     1/1/2015
a      6     1/1/2015
a      1     1/1/2015
c      1     1/1/2015

Sector Value Date
a      2     2/1/2015
b      10    2/1/2015
b      5     2/1/2015
c      8     2/1/2015
```

Is there a way to use the MongoDB aggregate framework to find the *difference* between each grouped sector for the two dates in question?

In other words is it possible to get an output like this:

```
a    -> (2+3+6) - 2 = 10 
b    -> 5 - (10+5) = -10
c    -> (8+1) - 8 = 1
```

Comment: If I understand it well, your two "data sets" are two different _collections_ ?

Comment: Sorry, that's not obvious - all the data is in the same collection

Comment: The sum for `b` should be `-10`, not `+10` -- I assume this is a typo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the aggregation framework and the [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to change the sign of the value on 2/1/2015, this is a simple sum.

Given that test collection:

```
{ name: 'a',      value: 2,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'b',      value: 5,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'c',      value: 8,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'a',      value: 3,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'a',      value: 6,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'a',      value: 1,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'c',      value: 1,     date: ISODate('2015-01-01') },
{ name: 'a',      value: 2,     date: ISODate('2015-01-02') },
{ name: 'b',      value: 10,    date: ISODate('2015-01-02') },
{ name: 'b',      value: 5,     date: ISODate('2015-01-02') },
{ name: 'c',      value: 8,     date: ISODate('2015-01-02') }
```

Here is how to achieve the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { date: { $in: [ ISODate('2015-01-01'), ISODate('2015-01-02') ] }}},
  { $project: { name: 1,
                value: { $cond: [ {$eq: [ "$date", ISODate('2015-01-01')]},
                                  "$value",
                                  { $subtract: [0, "$value"] } ]}}},
  { $group: { _id: "$name", total: { $sum: "$value" }}}
])
```

- the [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage keeps only the value for the given two days
- the [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage will keep the value as-is for documents whose date is equals to '2015-01-01', but will change the value *sign* for documents whose date is equals to '2015-01-02'
- finally, the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage will sum all values (positive and negatives).

Producing:

```
{ "_id" : "c", "total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "b", "total" : -10 }
{ "_id" : "a", "total" : 10 }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me, this makes a lot of sense